# What is the correct way to type an rtk query BaseQueryFn with custom DefinitionExtraOptions?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I want to use [custom base query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-basequery), and supply it with extra options. Here's a toy example:

```
import { BaseQueryFn, createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseQueryTest: BaseQueryFn<
  unknown,
  unknown,
  string,
  { customData: string }
> = async () => {
  throw new Error('Not implemented');
};

createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryTest,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Type 'BaseQueryFn<unknown, unknown, string, { customData: string; }, {}>' is not assignable to type 'BaseQueryFn<any, unknown, unknown, {}, {}>'. typescript (2322) [58, 3]
  Property 'customData' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ customData: string; }'.
```

What am I doing wrong, and what's the right way to type this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at this point, `DefinitionExtraOptions` can only contain optional values (as `extraOptions` itself is always optional). If you add a `?`, it works.